# Can you use 'doPost' in a Library?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, triggers, libraries

I'm trying to put a doPost inside an Apps Script library. Is that possible?
It doesn't seem to work like this?

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("hello");
}

function doPost(e) {
  MyLibrary.doPost(e)
}
```

Comment: Should work. What's the error?

Comment: Just get nothing. If I just put the URL in a browser it returns the 'hello', but if I try posting data which would usually work with doPost() if the code was there, I just get nothing. But that said, I just tried another function together with a working doPost and that doesn't work either. (I mean the doPost did work but the library function didn't) Maybe I'm doing the library setup wrong?

Comment: I've got it working, but I don't have much idea what changed. Thanks for telling me it ought to though, that added to my perseverance! If I work out what was wrong I'll post it but setting up library is kind of confusing to say the least.

Comment: Should it be `return MyLibrary.doPost(e)`?

Comment: Nope, it worked fine just as in the code above. I didn't work out why it was failing in the first place but perhaps it was my confusion over versions? I cleared everything out and started the library settings over again to keep it simple and got it to work.